# Importing OpenZeppelin loads all node_modules contracts into Ganache

Tags: truffle, ganache

I install OpenZeppelin's contracts `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`

Create a contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Mintable.sol";

contract NewCoin is ERC20Mintable {

  constructor() public {

  }
}
```

`truffle compile` (successful)

When I load Ganache it imports every single node_module contract into the "Contracts" tab and the program rapidly starts OOMing.

`truffle migrate` then kills it completely.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using VS Code with Truffle version:

```
Truffle v5.1.12 (core: 5.1.12)
Solidity - ^0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v8.17.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

Comment: Did you somehow end up with your node_modules folder inside your project contracts folder?

Comment: Nope, I think my folder structure is all fine - https://i.imgur.com/C1Ezzfu.png

Comment: OK this was a silly mistake. My build folder was full of artefacts from a previous test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone new to Truffle experiences something similar; build folder was full of old artefacts. Deleted them and compiled again to resolve.

Alternatively, run `truffle migrate --reset` to force the update.